# nltk tagged_words unexpected argument

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to learn NLTK by following instructions in a book. The code is:

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
brown_news_tagged = brown.tagged_words(categories='news', tagsets='universal')
```

However, the error I get is: `tagged_words() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tagsets'`

Comment: Which book are you using?

Comment: http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch05.html

Comment: @andi Does that particular book contain `tagsets='universal'`?

Comment: pardon! I mixed up links: http://www.nltk.org/book3/ch05.html

Comment: Have you tried using `tagset=...` instead of `tagsets=...`?

Comment: @summea I ve tried it. Still not working.

Comment: same book and same problem with @andi....

Comment: @JudyJiang Could you tell us what part (what section) of the book you are working through?

Comment: @summea It's "Natural Language Processing with Python (updated for python 3) chapter 4 in which I met the problem described here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few reasons why this could be happening:

- The book you are going through has been updated for *Python 3*
- NLTK traditionally [requires](http://www.nltk.org/install.html) *Python 2.x*
- There is an [*alpha version of NLTK 3.0*](http://www.nltk.org/nltk3-alpha/) that supports Python 3

If you choose to use Python 3 and the alpha version of NLTK 3.0, you can verify the availability of the `tagset` argument by using the following commands on a command line:

```
python3
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getargspec(brown.tagged_words)
```

After running those commands, we can see that the `tagset` parameter/argument is available:

```
ArgSpec(args=['self', 'fileids', 'categories', 'tagset'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=(None, None, None))
```

Looking back at the [NLTK book](http://www.nltk.org/book3/ch05.html) in Chapter 5, we can also see that the examples given in relation to the `universal` option indeed uses `tagset` (*singular* rather than *plural*) in order to obtain the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

The correct argument (I think) for python 2.7.8 is [now?] `simplify_tags=...`

Comment: as summea & others have pointed it out, simplify_tags doesn't work and has been replaced with tagset = 'universal' (I am using Python 2.7.11)